# I'm using TMDB api to show movie poster but I'm getting some errors

Tags: json, python-2.7

```
  **here is my code**

     import os
     import requests

      CONFIG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=Monsters+University&api_key=xxx'
        IMG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie?query=Monsters+University&api_key=xxx'
     KEY = 'xxx'

     def _get_json(url):
      r = requests.get(url)
     return r.json()

     def _download_images(urls, path='.'):
      """download all images in list 'urls' to 'path' """

for nr, url in enumerate(urls):
    r = requests.get(url)
    filetype = r.headers['content-type'].split('/')[-1]
    filename = 'poster_{0}.{1}'.format(nr+1,filetype)
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filepath,'wb') as w:
        w.write(r.content)

        def get_poster_urls(imdbid):
    """ return image urls of posters for IMDB id
    returns all poster images from 'themoviedb.org'. Uses the
    maximum available size.
    Args:
        imdbid (str): IMDB id of the movie
    Returns:
        list: list of urls to the images
"""
config = _get_json(CONFIG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY))
base_url = config['images']['base_url']
sizes = config['images']['poster_sizes']


  def size_str_to_int(x):
    return float("inf") if x == 'original' else int(x[1:])
    max_size = max(sizes, key=size_str_to_int)

posters = _get_json(IMG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY,imdbid=imdbid))['posters']
poster_urls = []
for poster in posters:
    rel_path = poster['file_path']
    url = "{0}{1}{2}".format(base_url, max_size, rel_path)
    poster_urls.append(url)

return poster_urls

 def tmdb_posters(imdbid, count=None, outpath='.'):
urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
if count is not None:
    urls = urls[:count]
_download_images(urls, outpath)

 if __name__=="__main__":
tmdb_posters('tt0095016')
```

please format the code accordingly iam fetching the json data using TMDB api but iam getting errors 
here are errors

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ayushblueluck/PycharmProjects/MovieDatabase/test.py", line 57, in <module>
tmdb_posters('tt0095016')
    File "C:/Users/ayushblueluck/PycharmProjects/MovieDatabase/test.py", line 51, in tmdb_posters
urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
      File "C:/Users/ayushblueluck/PycharmProjects/MovieDatabase/test.py", line 33, in get_poster_urls
base_url = config['images']['base_url']
KeyError: 'images'

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

But iam unable to figuring out the errors it seems like everything is right but urrghh these errors are not going i have tried everything

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should work if you change `CONFIG_PATTERN` to `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=<your_key>`

BTW, edited your question since you posted your API key in it.